# How can I make my own fabric replacement slats for my blinds?

Tags: windows, blinds

I need to replace the fabric slats on the vertical blinds in my house. I do not want vinyl ones in my house. My windows look out on a golf course from most of the rooms in my house. I have lived with them for 30 years and have lost some to the dogs and a few to wear. They are 57 inches long. I sew so that part should not be a problem. I am not sure what to use to stiffen the fabric. Or where to get the replacements plastic pieces that go in the top of the slats to hook into the rail. Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: What about a heavy-duty iron-on interfacing and laundry starch?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=replacement+slats+for+verticle+blinds

Answer (score 1):

Something like Craft Plastic would probably do the trick.

You can generally find Craft Plastic at arts and craft stores - its used commonly in scrap-booking.

A bit of an unusual item for a DIY question but in this case, appropriate, I think.